# Append child only to new elements, D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Everytime `draw` is called a `circle` gets appended to every `g` element.
How can i append `circle` only to new `g` elements? There is no data to bind to the `circles`

```
function draw(data){    
  var gs = svg.selectAll('g').data(data);

  gs.exit().remove();

  gs.enter().append('g')
    .attr("transform", function(d, i){return "translate(" + i*100 + "," + 0 + ")"; });

  var c = gs.append('circle')
    .attr('cx', function(d, i){return 100+i*200;})
    .attr('cy', 55)
    .attr('fill', 'cyan')
    .attr('r', 5)
    .transition()
    .duration(1000)
    .attr('r', 50);
 }

 draw([1, 2, 3, 4]);   // first time
 draw([1, 2, 3]);      // update
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic issue you are having is you are appending the circle to all the g elements, newly created or not. the .enter() method returns only the new ones.

Rather than using `gs.append('circle')`, use `gs.enter().append('circle')`, that way only the new elements will have a circle appended. Here is how I would write it.

```
function draw(data){    
 var gs = svg.selectAll('g').data(data);

 gs.exit().remove();

 gs.enter().append('g')
   .attr("transform", function(d, i){return "translate(" + i*100 + "," + 0 + ")"; })
   .append('circle')
   .attr('cx', function(d, i){return 100+i*200;})
   .attr('cy', 55)
   .attr('fill', 'cyan')
   .attr('r', 5)
   .transition()
   .duration(1000)
   .attr('r', 50);
}

draw([1, 2, 3, 4]);   // first time
draw([1, 2, 3]);      // update
```

Without a working example to test on, I'm not sure if `.attr('cx', function(d, i){return 100+i*200;})` will get the correct data or not. If not, you might need to append the circles in an each method on the group.

Comment: i want to append one `circle` to every `g` element, your code appends `circles` to `svg`

Comment: It shouldn't have. Now that you clarified your question, I modified the code to be simpler. I think that's what you are looking for.